# TkInter's __init__ says the global variable doesn't exist

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The idea's that the Label should recieve it's text from the main program, but even tho VSC says there is no problem on the code, when I hit 'run' it crashes.

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class results:
    def __init__(self, ):
        global root, Class

        root = tk.Tk()
        root.geometry("819x503+471+148")
        root.minsize(120, 1)
        root.maxsize(3844, 1061)
        root.resizable(1, 1)
        root.title("Results")
        root.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        root.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        root.configure(highlightcolor="black")

        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'
        font10 = "-family {Yu Mincho} -size 24 -slant italic"
        font11 = "-family {Segoe UI} -size 13 -underline 1"
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        if sys.platform == "win32":
            self.style.theme_use('winnative')
        self.style.configure('.',background=_bgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',foreground=_fgcolor)
        self.style.configure('.',font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.style.map('.',background=
            [('selected', _compcolor), ('active',_ana2color)])

        self.TFrame1 = ttk.Frame(root)
        self.TFrame1.place(relx=0.012, rely=0.02, relheight=0.96, relwidth=0.974)

        self.TFrame1.configure(relief='groove')
        self.TFrame1.configure(borderwidth="2")
        self.TFrame1.configure(relief="groove")

        self.TSubFrame1 = ttk.Frame(self.TFrame1)
        self.TSubFrame1.place(relx=0.025, rely=0.248, relheight=0.59
                , relwidth=0.296)
        self.TSubFrame1.configure(relief='groove')
        self.TSubFrame1.configure(borderwidth="2")
        self.TSubFrame1.configure(relief="groove")

        self.labelShowClass = ttk.Label(self.TSubFrame1)
        self.labelShowClass.place(relx=0.042, rely=0.035, height=259, width=215)
        self.labelShowClass.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.labelShowClass.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.labelShowClass.configure(font="TkDefaultFont")
        self.labelShowClass.configure(relief="flat")
        self.labelShowClass.configure(anchor='w')
        self.labelShowClass.configure(justify='left')
        self.labelShowClass.configure(text=Class) #Imma kms, why does it say it's not defined!?!?!

    def recieveClasses(self, classes):
        global Class
        Class = classes

    def start(self):
        global root
        root.mainloop()

    def close(self):
        global root
        root.destroy()
```

The main.py code, calling the object:

```
from interface.results import results

result = results()
result.recieveClasses("test")
result.start()
```

The error message saying it doesnt exist. Thing is: if I try to call global Class in any other method, other than **init**, it calls the damn variable without a problem. Only inside **init** that it crashes.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Dropbox\program\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    result = results()
  File "d:\Dropbox\program\interface\results.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.labelShowClass.configure(text=Class)
NameError: name 'Class' is not defined
```

Comment: `Class` is only defined once `results.recieveClasses` is called, which cannot happen until _after_ you have initialized a `results` instance. Also, why on earth are you using global variables in a class? And likewise, why do **NONE** of your class' methods use the instance they are defined on?

Comment: What do you mean "instance they are defined on?", also I'm using global cuz something like _self.Class = classes_ on `results.recieveClasses` didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future me and/or others that happen to fall on the same problem:

```
def recieveClasses(self, classes):
    self.labelShowClass.configure(text=classes)
```

No need to create any variables, just change the interface directly on the function.